# Audio Recorder Android

Tags: android, eclipse, audio, mediarecorder, android-mediarecorder

I'm doing a aplication to recorder the sound, but when I try to record the sound,the emulator is stopped because it ask me to insert an SD card. What I have to do? I couldn't do without an SD card ?

Thank you!

```
   package proiektua.proiektua;


import java.io.FileDescriptor;

import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;

import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;


public class MainActivity extends Activity  {

        int peticion = 1;
        Uri url1;
        private int STATE_CONFIGURE;
        private int mState = STATE_CONFIGURE;


        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
            // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
            getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
            return true;
        }

        public void grabar(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.Audio.Media.RECORD_SOUND_ACTION);
            startActivityForResult(intent, peticion);}

            public void setOutputFile(FileDescriptor fd) {
                    switch (mState) {
                case STATE_RECORD:
                        throw new RuntimeException("setOutputFile cannot be called while recording!");

                    case STATE_RELEASED:
                        throw new RuntimeException("setOutputFile called on an already released recorder!");
                    default:
                        break;
                }
        }

        public void reproducir(View v) {
            MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, url1);
            mediaPlayer.start();
        }

        protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK && requestCode == peticion) {
                url1 = data.getData();
            }
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the option to create an SDCard through the [mksdcard](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/mksdcard.html) command and associate it with the amulator.

Comment: but mksdcard is a img, where I put this?

Comment: Select the image through your IDE or mention it on the command line. Check out the configuration [on eclipse](http://i.stack.imgur.com/w9VwW.jpg) for example. You can select the SD card before starting the emulator.

Comment: I choose one image to my IDE and SDCard is desapear,ok. I give the button record and it record, but when I give the button play, there are a strange sounds...Why this? @ Deepak Bala

Comment: Yes I got that too. The emulator is never good at recording and playback. The audio that recorded with strange sounds worked perfectly on the real device.

Comment: But I have to present this proyect in a Computer... don't know how to fix it? @ Deepak Bala

Comment: No. Unfortunately I've not found a solution for it as yet. I've just switched to using a real device.

Answer (score 0):

please look at this function:

```
public void setOutputFile (FileDescriptor fd)

Added in API level 3
Pass in the file descriptor of the file to be written. Call this after setOutputFormat() but before prepare().
```

You can decide where to store the file.

also look at this example. 
http://androidfreakers.blogspot.co.il/2011/09/using-mediarecorder.html

Comment: and if I want to use this sound to do other function, for example to do the Fourier Fast Transform, how I choose this sound? the method public void setOutputFile (FileDescriptor fd) I have to put later or after "public void grabar"?

Comment: if you want to use fft i suggest you don't do it on a large file you can use Jtransform library and also try to use AudioRecorder instead of Media recorder to get the buffer you need.

Comment: Everithing that I done about MediaRecorder, have I to delete it? And when I do fft function, I put this in activity main or in another class?

Comment: I'll try to do with MediaRecorder, but where is the Jtransform library? Have I to download? I find in this page the fft function: http://www.cs.princeton.edu/introcs/97data/FFT.java. It's correct?

Comment: https://sites.google.com/site/piotrwendykier/software/jtransforms this is it. i suggest you learn a little more about object oriented programming before using it. you to decide on your own about where to put it. depends on the design